# Restrictibility to the case that $f$ is surjective in the proof that some restricted morhpism is finite locally free.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm reading Gortz's Algebraic Geometry, Prop. 14.121 and stuck at understanding a possibility of reduction to case of surjectivity of $f$.

In the Prop. 14.121 he states that

> Proposition 14.121. Let $f:X\to Y $ be a proper flat morphism of finite presentation and set $V:=\{y\in Y  ; \operatorname{dim}f^{-1}(y)=0 \}$. Then $V$ is open and closed in $Y$ and the restriction $f^{-1}(V) \to V$ of $f$ is finite locally free.

In the proof of the proposition, he argues as follows :

" This queston is local on $Y$ and thus we may assume that $Y$ is affine. Since $f$ is of finite presentation and all properties of $f$ are compatiable with inductive limits of rings (c.f. his book, p.259), we may assume, by Theorem 10.69, that $Y$ and hence $X$ is noetherian(c.f. his book prop. 10.9) Since $f$ is open(c.f. theorem 14.33) and closed(since $f$ is proper), we can restrict to the case that $f$ is surjective."

**My question is, why we may assume that $f$ is surjective?**

Assume that the restricted case is true.
Consider the restriction $\bar{f} : X \to \operatorname{im}f$. $\operatorname{im}f$ is open and closed.

First, by the reduction assumption( $\bar{f}$ is also proper, flat morphism of finite presentation ?), $V \cap \operatorname{im}f$ is open and closed in $\operatorname{im}f$ (?). ( So $V \cap \operatorname{im}f$ is open and closed in $Y$. ) And note that $V = ( V \cap \operatorname{im}f) \cup (V \cap (\operatorname{im}f)^{c})$. And can we deduce from these that $V$ is open/closed in $Y$?

Second, if $\bar{f}^{-1}(V\cap \operatorname{im}f)= f^{-1}(V\cap \operatorname{im}f) \to V\cap \operatorname{im}f $ is finite locally free, then $f^{-1}(V) \to V$ is also finite locally free?

Comment: Flat maps are open and proper maps are closed.

Comment: I know that. And how about next? Can you expalin more in detail?

Comment: An open and closed subset is either empty or union of connected components. So, if $Y$ is connected, the map is surjective.

Comment: @Mohan : I still don't know what is relation between your comment and my question. Why our statement is true in general if the case of surjectivity of $f$ is ture?

Comment: Your question in bold says why the map is surjective and that is what I answered.

Comment: Uhm.. some confusion. I said that why we 'may assume' that $f$ is surjective, not said that why $f$ is surjective.